# Drupal 7 OG Group Unsubscribe after given time period

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, subscription, organic-groups

I am new to drupal 7 and was willing to implement something like time based unsubscription from a OG Group.

I have users added in OG Group. 
I want to implement time based unsubscription of the users already added in the group say 'Computers'.

User say 'Tony' is added to the group 'Computers' today, now I wish that a user 'Tony' should be unsubscribed from the group 'Computers' after a subscription of 3 months (a specific time period).

A Notification message should be sent to user 'Tony'.

All the process should be based on systems current date and the joining date of user 'Tony' to the group 'Computers'.

Please help me with any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the rules module: http://drupal.org/project/rules

Once you've enabled the module, you can create a rule (Administration » Configuration » Workflow » Rules) that runs each time cron is run on your site.  I'm assuming cron runs hourly or daily.

On your new rule that runs with cron, you'll have to add several actions

1. Get group members from certain group
2. Loop on those members
3. Unsubscribe each user

Does that work for you?

---

Addition:

Another thing that may help you get your list of groups and/or group members for this is installing and using the Views Bulk Operations module: http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations

Rules integrates with that, so maybe you can do the following:

1. Create a VBO view that lists all your members from a certain group you're interested in keeping clean.  Use as a filter on your view the time they've been a member if you'd like...
2. Go back to your rule that runs on cron and choosing the following under 'Actions': 'Load list of entity ids from a VBO View' (screenshot attached)
   [image]
3. Then add a loop on those users (second action)
4. Then add an action for that loop that unsubscribes the users (third action)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried this, but there was a confusion in my head about using data variables in rules section. It would be very helpful, if you could help me with an tutorial.

Comment: How far did you get?  Which part did you get stuck on?

Comment: Cron can run weekly also. In rules section, in 'event' part I entered 'Cron maintenance tasks are performed' in 'actions' part I entered 'Unsubscribe user from group' with parameters as 'Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Group: [site:current-group]', but in condition part i am not able to retrive member details as it is based on data variables in drupal.For running of cron in 3 months i found that 'Elysia Cron' which is a module which enables administrator to run cron once in a month, or once a year or any other specified time as the administrator wants can be used.

Comment: It's a good idea to make cron run at least daily on a Drupal site because it performs lots of useful clean-up tasks and keeps your site running in a healthy, faster way.  It does things like help with the search index, etc.  :-)  I'm modifying my answer a little with another option that may help you with choosing the users/groups.  I hope that works!

Comment: i at last understood your method and it was really helpful and a great solution, i tried a couple of solutions ,but this did the trick. Thanks for the solution...